# Is there any automatic job to load AD-groups?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance

I have developed a landing page that can authorize its tiles to users. This process works with Active Directory (AD) security groups. Since we now have 5000 AD groups, the window to edit the tile takes much too long because the adgroups are always reloaded. Is there such an automatic process in .NET that only loads these ad groups once and then always takes them from these AD groups?

Comment: Yeah, its called static variable.

Comment: What exactly is always "reloading" the AD groups? Is it something you wrote? I think we need to see some code to understand the problem.

Comment: What is an "AD group"?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Active Directory security groups

Comment: "Since we now have 5000 AD groups" sounds really bad. Why do you have so many groups, how many users are there per group? Please show relevant code.